# Rabbit Priority Above 256

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, priority-queue

Has anyone seen/created a way to implement Rabbit to allow more than 256 levels of priority recently?

I've read https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html  but was hoping the following problem could be solved with newer updates:

I'm trying to accomplish a priority in that, if I have 1500 jobs and each job has 50 steps that get queued linearly after the previous step has finished, I want one particular job to have priority 1500 and each of it's steps to be prioritized over the other job's steps depending on timing. Anyone been able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The docs say this:

> The message priority field is defined as an unsigned byte, so in practice priorities should be between 0 and 255.

which is a limitation imposed by the AMQP protocol, so I'm pretty sure RabbitMQ won't address your issue